# Maximum Likelihood Estimation of Phase

Tags: maximum-likelihood-estimation

I'm trying to solve an exercise where I need to derive the MLE of the phase parameter.

I'm given the below signal with white noise $w[n] \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2) $, amplitude $A$, angular frequency $\omega \notin \{0, \pi\}$, $N$ measurements and unknown phase $\phi$.

$$
x[n]=A \cos (\omega n+\phi)+w[n], \; \; n= 1,...,N
$$

Usually I'd get the log-likelihood function, compute the first derivative, set it to zero and solve for the unknown parameter which is $\phi$ in this case. However, I am unable to solve for $\phi$ in the 1st derivative as I am can't extract it from inside the sine and cosine functions.

$$
\begin{gathered}
\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi} \ln p(x ; \phi)=-\frac{1}{\sigma^{2}} \sum_{1}^{N}(x[n]-A \cos (\omega n+\phi))(A \sin (\omega n+\phi)) \\
\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi} \ln p(x ; \phi)=0
\end{gathered}
$$

Can someone please help me solve this?

Comment: hi! You seem to know how to typeset formulas in $\LaTeX$! That's great. If you put them between `$`, for example as `$\phi$`, they get rendered as LaTeX (just for the future)

Comment: I wasn't aware of that and I was just adding the equations as images, thanks a lot for the hint! :)

Comment: You're welcome! When you want "freestanding" equation lines, you'd do `$$ w[n] \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2) $$`; you can also do `\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi} \ln p(x;\phi)  &= \ldots \\
& 0
\end{align}`

Comment: This problem is really tricky because of the non-additive noise  $w$ that appears both in and outside the cosine.

Comment: @MarcusMüller There's also [this](https://mathpix.com/) (but nevermind, just learned free is limited) - btw how'd you type that l a t e x? ironically this software can't figure it out

Comment: Outside the cosine you have double-u as a function of $n$ ($w[n]$).  _Inside_ the cosine you have double-u _times_ $n$ ($wn$).  Then in the second equation, you have **Roman** double-u times $n$ ($\mathrm w n$).  Is this right?  Do you really mean to have **omega** times $n$ ($\omega n$) inside the cosines?  Or do you really mean that $w[n] = wn = \mathrm w n$?.

Comment: And are the frequency and index ($wn$, $\mathrm w n$, or $\omega n$) known, i.e. the only unknowns are $w[n]$ and $\phi$?

Comment: You say that you are "computing the logarithm of the first derivative" of the likelihood function, but "$\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi} \ln p(x ; \phi)$" looks more like the first derivative of the _log likelihood_ function to me. Isn't there a difference between these two notions? Or are you believing that the two operations commute?

Comment: I think there was some confusion with the notation of the frequency and the noise. I've fixed it so that $w[n]$ represents the AWGN and $\omega$ the frequency.

Comment: @TimWescott yes, the only unknowns are $w[n]$ and $\phi$

Comment: @DilipSarwate the log-likelihood function is precisely what I meant, I thought the way I phrased it would be equivalent. Sorry about that.

Comment: @MarcusMüller The noise is additive and appears only outside. I'm sorry for the confusion I've caused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that there's a closed-form solution for the ML estimate of phase, but if you recast the definition of $x[n]$ to
$$x[n] = a \cos (\omega n) + b \sin (\omega n) + w[n], \; \; n= 1,...,N $$
then you can easily find the ML estimates of $a$ and $b$, and take $$\hat \phi = \tan^{-1}\frac{\hat b}{\hat a}.$$

[This PDF](http://www.ws.binghamton.edu/fowler/fowler%20personal%20page/EE522_files/EECE%20522%20Notes_12%20Ch_7A.pdf) seems to back up the assumption, though it calls the resulting estimator only an *approximate* maximum likelihood estimator.

[image: Screenshot from relevant page of linked PDF]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you cannot get an analytical solution. Or maybe you can assume the phase is very small, and use some approximation like $\cos \left( \phi \right) = 1$ and $\sin \left( \phi \right) = \phi$.